# QML: ListView delegate: items vs. MouseArea

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have the following code:

```
ListView {
    delegate: MyDelegate {
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            /*some other stuff*/
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `MyDelegate` contains checkboxes and `MouseArea` "steals" mouse events from them. They do not react on mouse events at all, i.e. do not work as expected.

I know about [`propagateComposedEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop) property of `MouseArea`...but I'll have to implement all of its mouse events (`clicked`, `pressed`, `released`,...) and check whether the mouse cursor is in the checkbox or not to set `mouse.accepted` property accordingly.

This is how I understood all of these currently. Is there any easier way, i.e. a way to be able to process all of the mouse events for areas that does not handle mouse events explicitly? For instance static text, progress bars, etc.

Comment: Did you try z-index?

Comment: How could I use it in my case? I mean MouseArea is a child of MyDelegate (am I right?). In this case there is no way to change Z order. Isn't it?

Comment: You can set `z` property for checkbox higher then for the mousearea

Comment: I've set z to 100 for checkboxes - did not help.

Comment: Haha. Setting Z property of MouseArea to -1 works just as needed!. Thanks. Please post as an answer. I'll mark it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply ***negative*** values to the [`z`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop) property of the `MouseArea`.

From the documentation:

> Items with a higher stacking value are drawn on top of siblings with a lower stacking order. Items with the same stacking value are drawn bottom up in the order they appear. Items with a negative stacking value are drawn under their parent's content.